# Response in browser vs Python requests

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

I'm practicing some programming this morning, and was trying to write a web crawler to get race results from this site: [1] http://www.iresultslive.com/desktop_results.php?op=overall&bib=&prev_bib=&eid=893&year=2014&racename=5k&subop=males.

When I am navigating on my browser, the link above returns a list of results from 1-50, and includes in the html a link to the "next" page. When I click on the next page, it goes to a page at [2] http://www.iresultslive.com/desktop_results.php?op=overall&subop=males&racename=5k&eid=893&year=2014&showplace=50&place=56. When I click next again, it goes to the same link as [2], EXCEPT that the parameters [3] showplace=100&place=121. So its pacing through a database of some kind, changing the parameters showplace and place each time.

However when I use the Python requests library on this site, I get slightly different behavior. The initial query to [1] returns the same result as the browser, with a link to [2]. However when I subsequently query [2] with Requests, the link for I get for "Next" does not point to [3], but points to [2] again. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

I've tried experimenting with HTTP headers, with cookies, but don't understand the situation.

Thanks!

Comment: I've made a quick test and I can see the correct URLs with Requests library. How are you doing the scrapping? BTW, you may be interested in [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org)...

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I figured out another way around it!